# Jenkins Pipeline: scm username/password as input parameters

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to pass the username/password to use to do a maven release in a pipeline.

I cannot register the credentials in Jenkins since each user need to use it's own credentials, so I need to pass them as parameters (much like credentials can be passed while doing a release with a maven job).

I tried to define them as job parameters in Jenkins, but then I cannot avoid logging them while passing them in the command line:

```
 sh "mvn -e -Dpassword=${SCMPW} -Dusername=${SCMUSR} ... release:prepare release:perfom"
```

Is there a way to obtain this?

Comment: If still relevent, use the credentials() parameter, such as exmplained there: https://docwhat.org/jenkins-user-credentials